# Windows cannot find the path to Office install folder. How can I solve this?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I bought today MS Office and tried to install it. After 10 Minutes the install was finished but, to my surprise, I could not open any of the products I just bought. The error message I got was:

> Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly.

But of course it is there...

```
C:\
λ  cd '.\Program Files (x86)\'
C:\Program Files (x86)
λ  cd '.\Microsoft Office\'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office
λ  cd .\root\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root
λ  cd .\Office16\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
λ  ls
-a----        2/23/2019   7:26 PM        1966152 WINWORD.EXE
```

So at this point im really not sure what to do..
Here is what i have tried

- Uninstall and Install
- Disable Firewall & Other Antivirus Programs
- Go through every forum I have found on the first page of google

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Check the PATH environment variable. If there is a single **invalid** path, then the rest of the path items cannot be read. Put MS Office first, to test.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you elaborate please. I still have not been able to fix this issue.

Comment: See https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/set-path-environment-variables-in-windows-10/